# Matching text and spoken audio

Tags: linux, audio, voice-recognition

I have some Chinese text and audio clips of someone reading the same text. Using some software, I have split the recording in key places (whenever the speaker took a rest), so I have many individual audio files. Within the text, I'd like to mark all of the places in which a split in the audio file occurs (e.g. place a "@" at the place where one audio file ends and the next begins).

- There is are no background noises and only in a few rare places does the text and voice differ.
- The text is hundreds of pages long and there are ten thousand audio files, so it would take forever to do this manually.

How can I mark the text or split the text up to match the splits in the audio files?

Comment: This may be a better question for http://dsp.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Have you solved issue? can you help me...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14228892/text-to-audio-and-audio-to-text-in-android

Answer (score 1):

Why dont you check julius search engine. But it needs training.